Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
PS D:\PDA\PDA\frontend> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\MSI.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed
5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\MSI.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             17.5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
The shared preferences package simply doesn't work.
